# fork process always returning > 0 i cannot figure out why?

Tags: c, fork

Hello i am creating a simple shell in C, currently i am having an issue with fork as it always seems to return a value > 0 even when i type in some non linux command like "ehshhduh" it will still print out"Chile process complete" instead of returning an Error message could anyone explain to me what i am doing wrong thanks?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


char str_tokens[50];

char * get_input() {
    pid_t pid; 
    char *tokens[30][50];
    char input[512];
    char *charp;
    char *burner[20];
  
    int i = 0;

while(true) {
   printf(">");
   if(fgets(input, 512, stdin) == 0 || strncmp(input, "exit", 4) == 0) {    /* reads in input from user no more than 512 chars including null terminator, program terminates if "exit" or CTRL-D is detected*/
     printf("exitting program");
       exit(0);
   } 

    const char delimiters[9] = {'&', ';', '\n', '|', ' ', '\t', '>', '<',}; 
    charp = strtok(input, delimiters); /* splits the string on delimiters */
    while (charp != NULL) {
      
         strcpy(str_tokens, charp);
        charp = strtok(NULL, delimiters);   // sets the char pointer to null
                                                //after each split of the string 
                                                //so the loop eventually terminates */
        } 
       char *args[] = {str_tokens, 0};  

    pid = fork();     // fork a child process
    if (pid == -1) { /* error occured */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occured with Fork");
        return 1;
    }
     else if (pid > 0) {  /* parent process */
        /* parent will wait for the child process to complete */
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Child process completed") ;
    }
    else if(pid == 0){ // (pid == 0)  /* this is the child process */
        execvp(args[0], args);          /* first param the file path, seconf is null terminated array of char pointers*/
        printf("this is the child process");
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);            /* in the case our exec never returns exit */
    }
   

    }
  
   return str_tokens;
}


void run_external(char* commands[50]) {
    commands = get_input();
}

int main () {
 run_external(get_input());
   return(0);
    
}
```

Comment: If `fork` does not return -1, then it returns twice and one of those returns is always 0.

Comment: how can i change this i am pretty new with C

Comment: Print the error messages to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  End the error messages with a newline so you're sure they'll appear (or as sure as you can be).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i have used stderr for when there is an error with the fork?

Comment: Hmmm — yes, I misspoke for the error after `fork()`.  The `printf()` after the `execvp()` is also an error message (it only appears if the `execvp()` fails) and it is printed to `stdout`, and it only appears if `stdout` is unbuffered because if it is line buffered or fully buffered, the `_exit()` call exits without flushing the standard I/O streams.  I would print most of those messages to `stderr`, and I'd prefix them with the PID (result of `getpid()`).  I'd also report on the results from `wait()` (which I'd probably call in a loop), rather than ignoring them entirely.

Comment: The double call to `get_input()` — one in `main()` and one in `run_external()` — is puzzling.  You have problems in that code, even if some other stuff seems to be working.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah that right i sorted that but your comment before the double  call on get_input has confused me how what is meant by " I would print most of those messages to stderr, and I'd prefix them with the PID (result of getpid()). I'd also report on the results from wait() (which I'd probably call in a loop), rather than ignoring them entirely." i am not entirely sure what you mean by that

Comment: @JamesTierney: it would take quite a lot of explaining.  The code I'd use is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  There's a settable option `ERR_PID` to report the PID in front of each reported message.  I'd be using `err_remark()` to write messages.  In effect, I'd be using `fprintf(stderr, "%d: message containing string '%s' and integer %d\n", getopt(), str, num);` or similar. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ I'd use `stderr` because messages written to it are not fully buffered — so they appear promptly.  The `wait()` loop would be: `int corpse, status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0) err_remark("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);` so that I know which process died and what its status was.  There are circumstances in which a process can inherit children that your program did not create — but they're obscure, and you're unlikely to encounter them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so will the process that died be identifiable through an int return value as you have used "%d" in this line of code err_remark("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);      I am not too sure what this line does as i am not that experienced with fork and child processes so could you explain please if you didn't mind

Comment: The `wait()` system call returns the PID of one dead child process (hence the variable `corpse`) and it's status.  The status encodes either the exit status or the signal that caused it to die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `fork` happens *before* you call `execvp` on the new program.

First you create a new process, then when you've done that successfully you attempt to start a new program in that process.  If the program name is invalid then `execvp` returns and you `_exit` the child process.

Also, you should call `perror` when `fork` or `execvp` fail.  That will print an error message describing why.

Comment: So i should use perror when pid == 0 and pid == -1 or is there something i am still not understanding, if i take out this line  _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  and replace it with what you have said will it print an error message and not "child process completed"?

Comment: @JamesTierney Use `perror` when `fork` fails, i.e. when it returns -1.  Also use it when `execve` returns at all because it doesn't return on success.  In the latter case you still want to `_exit` but you should call `perror` first.

Comment: i think i get you now this is the changes i have made

  pid = fork();     // fork a child process
    if (pid == -1) { /* error occured */
        perror("Error command %s does not exist: ", str_tokens );
        return 1;
    }
     else if (pid > 0) { 
       
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Child process completed") ;
    }
    else if(pid == 0){ 
        execvp(args[0], args);       
        printf("this is the child process");
        perror("command failed to execute");
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);           
    }

Comment: ah the message above doesn't seemed to have formatted the code properly is there a way i can message you and show u the changes i have made?

Comment: @JamesTierney `perror` just takes a string, not formatting like `printf`.  A `fork` failure also has nothing to do with whether the command you want to run is valid or not.

Comment: how would i deal with if the command failed to exist then?

Comment: @JamesTierney That's when `execve` would fail.

Comment: ah so i should include that error message in where pid == 0 also i have a quick question any ideas when i type in 'ps aux' it doesn't do anything am i not right in believing thats a valid UNIX command?